# Сложности с CASE

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/HappyCougar/s56zJ/17/show

Редко пользуюсь CASE и столкнулся с проблемой. Почему не работает?

Comment: а так http://jsfiddle.net/s56zJ/20/

Comment: кейс так и не заработал, он должен менять буквы

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[@HappyCougar](/users/5149/happycougar)](/users/5149/happycougar) то, что у вас написано с тысячей case - это адский говнокод. Гораздо проще и красивее сделать так:

```
function decode(str) {
    var first  = "abcdefghijklmopqrstufvxyz";
    var second = "ydfkprzabgcnjwixldhvuotsm";

    return str.split('').map(function(item, i) { 
       var pos = first.indexOf(item);   
       return second[pos];
    }).join('')
}

decode('abc') // "ydf"
```

[Результат](http://jsfiddle.net/mANT5/)

И еще - в вашем алфавите пропущена буква **n**

Comment: мой фэйл, спасибо